# Bind SQL database to combobox

Tags: c#, sql, combobox, binding

I have this program in which a combobox is supposed to retrieve data from a table in my database. It seems that getting the combobox filled from another class is not working. I have my form class and a 'Database' class. The latter contains my SQL query, connection string etc.

Now, I thought the 'binding' part would be as easy as creating an instance of my form class. Like this:

```
Keukenhulp KH = new Keukenhulp();

connection.Open();

SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT Gebruikersnaam FROM Gebruikers", connection);
SqlDataReader dr = query.ExecuteReader();

while (dr.Read())
{
    KH.cboxUser.Items.Add(dr["Gebruikersnaam"]);
}
connection.Close();
```

Obviously I'm not sure whether the rest of my stuff is correct. There seems to be a load of different solutions for this, this is simply one I've been trying.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Here is the easiest/modern way to bind your database to your UI [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-simple-data-application-with-wpf-and-entity-framework-6). No need to deal with SQL stuff anymore.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the Form. You need to access the instance that is already open. Forms are just classes. If you create two `FooObjects` and set a property on the first one you will not also see the property set on the second one. Same with forms.

Comment: @BassemAkl you can't say everyone should always use EF. OP is clearly inexperienced and trying to integrate EF into this project would probably derail it significantly.

Comment: What is error/problem after executing this code?

Comment: @SurjitSD That's the thing: there's no error at all. The combobox just doesn't update or anything.

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm not sure if I get what you're saying. Mind telling me what I should do here? Not to sound dumb or anything (even though you are correct to say that I am inexperienced). Just need some 'visual' to understand what you're saying. :P

Comment: This is one of the most asked c# questions on SO. Take a look here: https://grantwinney.com/passing-data-between-two-forms-in-winforms/

Comment: Maybe this will help you understand a little more: After you close the connection do this: `KH.Show();`

Comment: @Crowcoder Thank you kindly, Sir! Helped me fixing the issue, works now :)